# mypy type checking on Callable thinks that member variable is a method

Tags: python, mypy

When I run mypy over the following code I see several errors:

```
from typing import Callable, Type


def class_creator(outside_reference: Callable[[str], None]) -> Type[object]:
    class SomeClass():
        reference: Callable[[str], None]

        def __init__(self) -> None:
            self.reference = outside_reference
            super().__init__()

        def __str__(self):
            self.reference("SomeClass instance")

    return SomeClass


def callback(string: str) -> None:
    print("Prepping: " + string)


instance = class_creator(callback)()
print(instance)
```

Here are the errors:

```
test.py:9: error: Cannot assign to a method
test.py:9: error: Invalid self argument "SomeClass" to attribute function "reference" with type "Callable[[str], None]"
test.py:9: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Callable[[str], None]", variable has type "Callable[[], None]")
```

Line #9 is `self.reference = outside_reference`.

I'm basically positive that I'm just misunderstanding something, but I just can't see where I'm going wrong.

This is the minimal reproducible reference. If I change the types from `Callable[[str], None]` to `int` (and don't actually call it), then it runs just fine without showing any errors. It's only when I switch to `Callable` that it starts showing these errors.

What should my annotations be here?

Comment: I have a solution for you: if you remove `reference` declaration (line #6) errors will disappear. I have some thoughts (about `mypy` handling callable fields declarations as methods declarations), but not sure if they are correct

Comment: That would solve it, sure, but I want the annotation there so it's clear what the types are to anyone using this code.

Answer (score 6):

Until the issue in https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/708 is fixed, one clean way to work around this is to make the callable attribute optional, and wrap it in a method with an assert:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, Optional
class SomeClass:
  _reference: Optional[Callable[[], Any]]

  def reference(self) -> Any:
    assert self._reference is not None
    return self._reference()

  def __init__(self, reference):
    self.reference = reference

c = SomeClass(lambda: 42)
print(c.reference())
```

```
$ mypy test.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: This answer has a better workaround compared to @user240438 's answer.

Comment: How is this clean? :P

Answer (score 5):

A similar but shorter workaround is to annotate the member with a `Union` type, duplicating the `Callable` type:

```py
from typing import Callable, Union
class SomeClass:
  reference: Union[Callable[[], int], Callable[[], int]]

  def __init__(self, reference: Callable[[], int]):
    self.reference = reference

c = SomeClass(lambda: 42)
print(c.reference())
```

Comment: You can also use Union[Callable[[], int], NoReturn] to make it shorter.

Answer (score 3):

For the time being, MyPy just doesn't support you doing this. Support for this pattern is tracked in GitHub issue 708: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/708

The closest pattern in most cases will be to define an abstract class with a method like `execute`, then have callers subclass this with their implementation, instantiate this, and supply the instance as the argument instead of the callback. You can see this approach in older Java codebases (before Java 8), as a common use case for anonymous inner classes. This is, of course, tedious.

Alternatively, you could simply ask mypy to ignore the violations.